# create new variable based on year for time series

Tags: r, time-series, panel

```
gvkey = id
data = dataframe
data$t <- NA;
data[data$year = 2005, "t"] <- 1
data[data$year = 2006, "t"] <- 2
data[data$year = 2007, "t"] <- 3
data[data$year = 2008, "t"] <- 4
data[data$year = 2009, "t"] <- 5
data[data$year = 2010, "t"] <- 6
```

I want to create variable "t":

```
gvkey    year     t
1004     2005     1
1004     2006     2
1004     2007     3
1004     2008     4
1004     2009     5
1004     2010     6
1013     2005     1
1013     2006     2
1013     2007     3
1013     2008     4
1013     2009     5
1013     2010     6
.....
```

Somehow my code does not work. Do you have any idea why?

Is there a more efficient way to run this code?

I am new to R and would really appreciate your help.

column of interest

[image]

Comment: Is there some logic behind the replaced values?

Comment: I have added some additional rows to show the logic behind it

Comment: Thanks for more information. See my edited solution

Comment: `data$t <- match(data$year, unique(data$year))`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding thanks ! that was fast :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
data$t <- data$year - min(data$year) + 1
```